# Java OOP optimising code

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, code-duplication

I am working on my Java assignment - Minesweeper game clone. I have two almost identical (only text label and text frame differ) methods gameWon() and gameLost() which are responsible for showing "Game Won!"/"Game Lost" window at the end of the game. I know that code duplication is bad practice so I want to optimize it. The problem is that I am kinda new to OOP and I'm not really sure how to do it. Maybe I could merge those methods into one somehow to act differently in different situations or maybe inheritance would be useful. I don't really know and hope some of you could help me a little. Thanks for your answers.

Here's the code of those methods:

**gameOver**

```
public static void gameOver() {

        F1 = new JFrame("Game Over"); 
        F1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        F1.setSize(360, 120);
        Container content = F1.getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Sorry, you have lost this game! Better luck next time.",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 40));
        content.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }); 
        content.add(button);

        button = new JButton("Restart This Game");  
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                F1.dispose();
                Board.doRepaint();
            }
        });         
        content.add(button);

        button = new JButton("Play Again"); 
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                F1.dispose();
                restartGame();
            }
        });         
        content.add(button);

        F1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        F1.setVisible(true); 
    }
```

**gameWon**

```
public static void gameWon() {  
   F1 = new JFrame("Game Won"); 
   F1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

   F1.setSize(360, 120);
   Container content = F1.getContentPane();
   content.setBackground(Color.white);
   content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

   JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Congratulations, you have won the game!",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
   textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 40));
   content.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        System.exit(0);
     }
  }); 
  content.add(button);

  button = new JButton("Restart This Game");    
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        F1.dispose();
        Board.doRepaint();
    }
  });       
  content.add(button);

  button = new JButton("Play Again");   
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        F1.dispose();
        restartGame();
    }
  });       
  content.add(button);

  F1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  F1.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: You could create a generic `GameComplete` version which takes in a couple strings. That would allow you to reuse the same code and have different text displayed

Answer (score 1):

You should have just one method, call it `gameOver(....)`, and at first glance, you need only two arguments, `title`, and `message`. Then, change only two lines of code:

```
public static void gameOver(final String title, final String message) {
  .....
  F1 = new JFrame(title);
  .....
  JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(message ,SwingConstants.CENTER);
}
```

Then, instead of calling two methods, call the same method with different arguments:

```
gameOver("Game Won", "Congratulations, you have won the game!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you could do is take the strings for the title and message as parameters, or by taking a boolean parameter that denotes if the game has been won and have a boolean test in the method set the strings, something like:

```
public static void gameOver(boolean won) {
    ....
    F1 = new JFrame(won?"Game Won":"Game Over");
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void gameEnd(boolean hasWon) {

    String title = hasWon ? "Game Won" : "Game Over";
    F1 = new JFrame(title); 
    F1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    F1.setSize(360, 120);
    Container content = F1.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    String message = hasWon ? "Congratulations, you have won the game!" :
          "Sorry, you have lost this game! Better luck next time.";
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(message,SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 40));
    content.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }); 
    content.add(button);

    button = new JButton("Restart This Game");  
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            F1.dispose();
            Board.doRepaint();
        }
    });         
    content.add(button);

    button = new JButton("Play Again"); 
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            F1.dispose();
            restartGame();
        }
    });         
    content.add(button);

    F1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    F1.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking a bit more closely at the code, it won't be enough to pass a boolean or String parameter only as suggested in other answers. The work you'll have to to is to **identify code common and different** to all (here: two) methods. In your case, I'd come up with this:

- Title
- Message
- Button 1 Message
- Button 1 Listener
- Button 2 Message
- Button 2 Listener

  ```
  public static void showTwoButtonMessage(String title, String message,
   String button1Message, ActionListener listener1,
   String button2Message, ActionListener listener2){
  //...
  }
  ```

Thus you have a neat little method you can **re-use** to display **any** two button window.